# How to chang cellStyle of WPF Datagrid.Column

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void dataGrid_show_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)               
{
   if (dataGrid_show.Columns != null && (dataGrid_show.Columns.Count + 1) % 2 == 1)
   {
        e.Column.CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
        e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty,
                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue)));
                e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(
                    new Setter(DataGridCell.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, 
                               HorizontalAlignment.Left));
   ....
   }
}



private void dataGrid_show_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)               
{
   if (dataGrid_show.Columns != null && (dataGrid_show.Columns.Count + 1) % 2 == 1)
   {
        e.Column.CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
        e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(
                            new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty,
                                       new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue)));
        e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(
                            new Setter(DataGridCell.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, 
                                       HorizontalAlignment.Left));
    ....
   }
}
```

[image]

The column line is this,why?

Comment: This behaviour is caused by setting the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left`. The [default value is Stretch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx), which makes the cell fill the available space.
To align the `Text` use `HorizontalContentAlignment` instead, but since `Left` is the default value here, you don't really need to set any Alignment at all...

Comment: thanks very much!
I use center style,but It nothing happened,code below:

 e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));